# Question about divisors

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, elliptic-functions

Let $\Lambda=<2\omega_1,2\omega_2>$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$, $C=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ an elliptic curve. Let $O(0,0)$ (neutral element of the lattice), and $A \in \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ point of finite order (say, $k$).

How do I find the dimension and a basis of $l(nO)$ and $l(nO-mA)$?

For $l(nO)$ its dimension is $n$ and I think $\{1,\wp,\wp',\ldots,\wp^{(n-2)}\}$ would be a basis.
For $l(nO-mA)$ I am unsure of the dimension (is it $\deg(nO-mA)=n-m$?). Also, I do not know how to find a basis?

Comment: What is $A$ and why the factor $2$ in the definition of the lattice? (My guess is that you want $A=\operatorname {class of} (\omega_1, \omega_2)\in \mathbb C/\Lambda$ ).

Comment: I think, $O$ and $A$ are classes. @user145836 have you heard about Riemann-Roch theorem?

Comment: $A$ is any point in the lattice, not necessarily of order 2.

Comment: @user145836 I don't think you mean what you write: points in the lattice give $O$  on the elliptic curve and then the question doesn't make much sense. Please post the exact reference to the exercise (or is it homework?) instead of your interpretation of it.

Comment: I do not have a reference for this problem; I had something similar for homework I didn't do. What I don't know is how to give an explicit basis for $l(nO-mA)$ where $A$ is a point of finite order. For $l(nO)$ I can give a basis one basis i.e. $\{1,\wp,...,\wp^{(n-2)}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as to imply that $A$ is a point of two-torsion on the elliptic curve, i.e. $A\neq 0$ and $2A=0$ in the underlying group.

a) We have by Riemann-Roch:

$ l(nO)=
\left  \{\begin  {align} 
0 \; \operatorname {if} \; n\lt 0\\
1 \;\operatorname {if} \; n=0\\
n \;\operatorname {if} \; n\gt 0
\end {align} 
\right. \ $

b) Using Riemann-Roch again we get:

$ l(nO-mA)=
\left  \{\begin  {align} 
0 \; \operatorname {if} \; n-m\lt 0\\
n-m \;\operatorname {if} \;n-m\gt 0
\end {align} 
\right. \ $
If $n=m$ , we have by moreover invoking  Abel's theorem:
  $ l(nO-nA)=
\left  \{\begin  {align} 
1 \; \operatorname {if} \; n\in 2\mathbb Z\\
0 \; \operatorname {if} \; n\notin 2\mathbb Z
\end {align} 
\right. \ $

**Edit**
In the case the OP asks about in the comments where  $A\neq 0$ is an arbitrary point of the elliptic curve $C$ , the last case of my answer should be modified to :

If $n=m$ , we have by moreover invoking  Abel's theorem:
  $ l(nO-nA)=
\left  \{\begin  {align} 
1 \; \operatorname {if} \; nA=0 \in C\\
0 \; \operatorname {if} \; nA\neq 0 \in C
\end {align} 
\right. \ $

Comment: A is any point in the lattice, not necessarily of order 2. What is the basis for $l(nO-mA)$? How do I explicitly construct it?

Comment: I have written a comment to your question addressing that point.